# Make interface attachment permanent in Xen 3.2.1 Debian Lenny Dom0

Tags: debian, xen, interface

I'm trying to add interfaces to a DomU (either on the fly or after reboot) and the attach-interface script works just fine.

The problem is that when I reboot the DomU the interfaces added are "lost"....

Is there a way to save the interface configuration?

I tried adding vif=[''] line to the *.cfg file but with no success.

Can somebody give me a hint on what to do?

Answer (score 1):

Look for the xenstore: http://wiki.xensource.com/xenwiki/XenStoreReference

" ... XenStore is used ...  as a mechanism of creating and controlling Domain-U devices."

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the replies.

The problem was not in making the interface configuration persistant but rather in making the interface itself persistant when the DomU is rebooted after attaching it.

For the time being, I'm simply avoiding adding interfaces....

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I really understand what your problem is.

Here is an example configuration which is currently functionnal for a Xen 3.2.1 on Debian Lenny but also works for Xen 4.0.

```
vif         = [ 'ip=188.165.xx.17,mac=00:16:3E:E4:F7:FA', 'ip=188.165.xxx.13,mac=00:16:3E:E4:47:6A' ]
```

This is extremely useful in a network-route configuration as it is used for the routing taking place in the dom0.

If it's IP configuration for the domU itself, it has nothing to do with Xen. Just make the network configuration persistant in the domU.